# error an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.get'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to curve the borders of a login form and when I hover over the "Form2.Width" it shows error "an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Width.get'", And when I run the program of course it doesn't curve.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
GraphicsPath newgraph = new GraphicsPath();
            newgraph.StartFigure();
            newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), 180, 90);
            newgraph.AddLine(10, 0, Form.Width - 20, 0);
            newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(Form2.Width - 10, 0, 10, 10), -90, 90);
            newgraph.AddLine(Form2.Width, 20, Form2.Width, Form2.Height - 10);
            newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(Form2.Width - 10, Form2.Height - 10, 10, 10), 0, 90);
            newgraph.AddLine(Form2.Width - 10, Form2.Height, 20, Form2.Height);
            newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, Form2.Height - 10, 10, 10), 90, 90);
            newgraph.CloseAllFigures();
            Form2.Region = new Region(newgraph);
              }
        }
```

Comment: `this.Width` not `Form2.Width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the class name. You must use the instance of the created class. With the keyword `this.Width` you can access the form itself

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GraphicsPath newgraph = new GraphicsPath();
   newgraph.StartFigure();
   newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), 180, 90);
   newgraph.AddLine(10, 0, this.Width - 20, 0);
   newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(this.Width - 10, 0, 10, 10), -90, 90);
   newgraph.AddLine(this.Width, 20, this.Width, this.Height - 10);
   newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(this.Width - 10, this.Height - 10, 10, 10), 0, 90);
   newgraph.AddLine(this.Width - 10, this.Height, 20, this.Height);
   newgraph.AddArc(new Rectangle(0, this.Height - 10, 10, 10), 90, 90);
   newgraph.CloseAllFigures();
   this.Region = new Region(newgraph);
}
```